# "In" vs. "after" for future talk

Tags: prepositions, future

> The class will be over in 10 minutes.
>
> The class will be over after 10 minutes.

I know the first is correct but why?

Comment: How do you "know the first is correct"?

Comment: It's correct because native speakers don't say the second sentence.

Answer (score 17):

In OP's examples, *"in"* and *"after"* both specify a future time relative to the present moment. There's no grammatical rule saying either preposition is correct or wrong - it's just idiomatic preference that most people would use *"in"*.

Given that *"in"* is a somewhat "metaphoric" usage here, I suspect there's a tendency to only use it in simple constructions where it's *relative to the present moment*.

When speaking of some situation in the past, there is no *"present moment"* - so we need to explicitly state the time/event that we're counting our 10 minutes from. In such contexts, we're more likely to use *after* (or *within, following*, etc.) because the whole situation is more complex, so we choose our words more carefully. *"I went to the bar, but I left after 10 minutes"*.

Comment: *The owner told me that I had to leave **in** 10 minutes.* Here **in** sounds better than **after**.

Comment: And what about *the class will end after 10 minutes of questions*?

Comment: @TimLymington: In that case, the base "temporal reference" is *the time at which the question period started*. Maybe didn't express myself well in the answer text, but what I meant was that *"in"* usually implies the reference is "now, the present moment". For all other contexts, *"after"* is more suitable.

Comment: @Noah: Per with my comment to Tim, in your example, *"in"* means *at the (then) "present moment" when the owner was speaking*.

Comment: @Noah, I would read a difference between *in* and *after* in your sentence:  If the owner told me that I had to leave in 10 minutes, he said that 10 minutes from now, I must depart.  If he told me I had to leave after 10 minutes, then it took 10 minutes after I arrived for him to tell me to leave (immediately).

Comment: @Hellion: That interpretation only comes into play in a reported speech context *("He told me to leave after 10 minutes")*. In that case we naturally associate *"after"* with the act of telling, so we have to assume some event 10 minutes earlier to provide the "reference start time" (when he and/or I arrived, when he came over and started talking to me, or some other time/event just mentioned earlier in the narrative).

Answer (score 6):

They are both correct; although, if I wanted to be more precise, I would probably say it like this:

> *The class will end in 10 minutes*.

Going back to your two examples: right *now*, class is *in session*, but *in* ten minutes, class will *end*, and *after* 10 minutes, class *will have ended*, (or, put another way, *class will be over*).

[image]
Either one can work, however, because we don't usually give much thought to the relationships between time, changes of state, and times of state transitions – not in general conversation, at least. If it's now 12:50, and class runs until 1 o'clock, we don't generally make distinctions between 1:00 (when the bell rings) and 1:00:02 (when we're in the process of standing up) and 1:00:37 (when we are walking out the door).  All we really pay attention to is, *"Class is done at one!"*

In a scientific paper describing some low-level process, we might need to pay more attention to our prepositions, and not say "after" when we mean "in", and vice-versa.  For the end of class, however, either preposition suffices.

Answer (score 6):

To me, 'After ten minutes' suggests certainly not before ten minutes have passed, and might be quite a bit later. 'In ten minutes' is fairly precise but might mean a little less than ten minutes.

Comment: A (The) significant point that everyone seems to have missed.

Comment: To me, in ten minutes is like any time from 1 to 9 minutes later than now are possible. For example, he can eat 10 apples in 10 minutes.

Answer (score -1):

In this context, I believe 'in' and 'after' are prepositions because there is a time constraint. I think 'in' is used for near future and 'after' is for far future.

Comment: um.. I don't see the difference...

Comment: I don't think so. *"I left after 10 minutes"* is probably more likely than *"I left **in** 10 minutes"* in most contexts.

Comment: ah yes.. I didn't think about that while giving my 2 cents :-).. thanks :-)