# What does this mean - "Please call me in 30 minutes"?

Tags: meaning

I'm confused about "in" used in the above sentence.

Does it mean "Please call me after 30 minutes" or does it mean "please call me within 30 minutes" ?

Comment: It means after 30 minutes. See [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/74158/94324)

Comment: Janus - Sorry i meant "within 30 minutes" not "before 30 minutes"

Answer (score 1):

*Please call me in 30 minutes.*

Wait 30 minutes and then call me.

Answer (score -1):

You have to call *within* 30 minutes.

Comment: I don't think this is correct...

Comment: Hello, Khaulat Nassor, and welcome to English Language and Usage. It seems to me that the statement that the poster asks admits three possible answers: (1) call no later than in 30 minutes; (2) call no sooner than in 30 minutes; (3) call in exactly (or approximately) 30 minutes. Since you have taken the view  that option (1) is the correct interpretation of the statement, you could greatly strengthen your answer by explaining why that answer—and not either of the other two—is the correct one. Please consider providing some reference-work support (with links, if possible) for your position.